# Making a query to Solr taking into account proximity matching between keywords

Tags: solr, lucene, information-retrieval

I have a list of keywords (+- six words) and I need a query that taking into account the proximity matching between keywords. The retrieval documents don't need to has all the keywords, but the documents that have these keywords more proximity will be more relevant.

I tried `text:"word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6"~5` but no documents was retrieval. I think this is due to a large number of keywords and the need for them to be close.

I tried too `text:word1 text:word2 text:word3 text:word4 text:word5 text:word6` but this query don't take into account proximity matching between words.

Comment: in quotes if you use 6 words "word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6" this means all are mandatory in the field and the distance of 5 indicates from any word in the query all words would not be more then 5 words far so you can increase proximity if you are not sure.

Comment: @CodeMagic yes, but has some way to consider proximity even one of the words is not in the document?

Answer (score 1):

Try to increase the proximity value e. g. "word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6"~15 and combine it with additional boolean queries. So you get:

```
text:("word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6"~15 word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6)
```

Documents containing the words within 15 words should now be ranked higher than documents with the words anywhere or only some of the words.

Adjust the proximity value to your needs.

Comment: Thank you, it helps me a lot. But when one of the words is not in documents the proximity does not work. Some way to consider proximity even one of the words is not in the document?

Comment: There are some options with eDismax Parser to boost word pairs or word triples. See https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html the pf2 and pf3 parameter.